# syslog for netstat to get no. of connection from each IP range

Tags: connection, syslog, rsyslog, netstat

I have a server which keeps on receiving request from two other servers from different IP ranges. I need to know how can I setup a cronjob which keeps on checking number of connection made by each server every second and keep on updating the result in a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

```
while true; do netstat -punta | grep ESTABLISHED | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -n; sleep 1; done
```

Can't use cron though. Should load it through systemd or something.

---

You probably want something like this though:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "New Connection"
```

From there you can start controlling what is going on with contrack.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139285/limit-max-connections-per-ip-address-and-new-connections-per-second-with-iptable

It's really not clear what your **actual** problem is, but if you ask that instead of trying to do what ever you are trying to do, we might be able to help out more.